# Launching a specific viewController by URLScheme in iOS

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, url-scheme

I want to send a link in an email to launch a specific UIViewController (it is actually a UITableViewController). I can get my app to open from the link using a CustomURL scheme and I have written the URLHandler method (the newest one not the deprecated one) and I can parse the URL, but I just cannot get the page to open. I am using storyboards, and a UINavigatorController and UITabBarController. The StoryboardID of the Scene I want to open is "ApprovalView".

When I run the following code I get the following error:

UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with

I am running it now form a button within the app. If I actually tap on a URL link the app just hangs.

I looked at other StackOverflow posts on this error and it seems to mean that I have hooked up a view to two viewControllers. I believe that is because of the line

ApprovalViewController *appViewController =
              [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApprovalView"];

However the suggested solutions don't seem to work, I believe because I am using starboards. Could I just call my segue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                  openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
               annotation:(id)annotation {

      // Get the host and query
      // the host is what expense to go to and the query is the noteID
      NSString *tmpHost = [[NSString alloc] init];
      tmpHost = [[url host] substringFromIndex:1];
      NSString *tmpQuery = [[NSString alloc] init];
      tmpQuery = [url query];

      // Go to a page

      // UIViewController *expenditureView =
      //      [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApprovalView"];

      // UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]
      // initWithRootViewController:expenditureView];

      //    UIViewController *expenditureController =
      //    [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
      //    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApprovalView"];
      //    UINavigationController *navVC =
      //    [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
      //    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
      //    UIViewController *currentVC = self.window.rootViewController;
      //    _window.rootViewController = navVC;
      //    [currentVC presentViewController:navVC animated:NO completion:nil];

      UIStoryboard *storyboard =
          [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

      ApprovalViewController *appViewController =
          [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApprovalView"];
      UINavigationController *navController = [appViewController.storyboard
          instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
      navController.view = appViewController.view;
      _window.rootViewController = navController;
      UIViewController *currentVC = self.window.rootViewController;
      [currentVC presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];

      // [self.window addSubview:self.navVC.view];
      // [self.window setRootViewController:self.navVC];

      // Navigation

      // UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
      //[navVC pushViewController:expenditureView animated:NO];

      //[expenditureView.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE
      // animated:YES];

      // self.window.rootViewController = expenditureView;

      return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that every tab should have a different Navigation Controller?

Comment: no, there is only one navigation controller is enough for route view controller in storyboard. No need for every tab.

Comment: try this as no need to pass navigation controller object to present vie : [currentVC presentViewController:appViewController animated:NO completion:nil];